# Can't run abaqus in ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with GPU(CUDA) accelerator. Initializing the CUDA Driver NO_DEVICE

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, gpu-driver

When I run run abaqus2022 with `abaqus job=jobname cpus=4 gpus=1 int`.
The following error message will appear.

```
USING ACCELERATOR PLATFORM_CUDA
Error initializing the CUDA Driver NO_DEVICE
WARNING: GPUAcceleration disabled
```

---

Here is the environment of my computer

```
NVIDIA-SMI 525.60.11    Driver Version: 525.60.11    CUDA Version: 12.0   
NVIDIA Corporation GA100GL [A30 PCIe]
```

i use `nvidia-driver-525-open` to installed the nvidia driver.

I can run pytorch with CUDA, and also can run Abaqus without GPU accelerator.
And I think I set the environment variables for abaqus correctly.
like:

```
$export
declare -x ABA_ACCELERATOR_TYPE="PLATFORM_CUDA"
```

I also write `os.environ["ABA_ACCELERATOR_TYPE"]="PLATFORM_CUDA" # Nvidia`
at the end of the `abaqus_v6.env` file.

Can anyone tell me what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by consulting dassault systemes.

```
Abaqus/Standard analyses using GPU acceleration on Linux may fail to find GPU card. It does not find the card due to
the presence of the libcuda.so in the installation_dir/2022/EstPrd/linux_a64/code/bin directory.
```

### Workaround:

Create a subdirectory name keepcuda in the installation_dir/2022/EstPrd/linux_a64/code/bin directory. Move
the following files: `libcuda.so`, `libcuda.so.1`, and `libcuda.so.418.39` to the newly created keepcuda subdirectory so that the
files do not interfere with the driver installed on the system (in /usr/lib64). Note the subdirectory name is not important.

> This issue does not occur in release 2021, only in R2022